# What is the music that plays when Juzo sacrificed himself to save Itachi?

Tags: naruto, music

In *Naruto Shippuden* ep. 456 at around 14:48-15:35, there's a music which plays after Juzo sacrificed himself to save Itachi. The music [starts at 5:09 in this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/VCNSY5JC1JA?t=5m9s).

Comment: It's ep456 @ 14:48-15:35. I can't find it in OST2 or OST3, unless it's a tiny bit in the middle of another track (which it probably is, if it's even been released at all). I'm starting to think that it's not a released track. I've spent all the time I'm willing to spend today, but I'll see if I can find it tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

It's 100% Sai's Theme Song. The bit you hear in the Juzo death scene starts at 0:27 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=enD0LhHJ8Gw

Answer (score 0):

I think it's [Sai's theme song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=enD0LhHJ8Gw) or Danzo's or Konoha's root.